# I would like to use a combination of map(), lambda and enumerate

Tags: python

My requirement to make me more familiar with the functionality of lambda: a combination of map(), lambda, enumerate() and list().

I would not like to use a list-comprehension or other functions at this stage.

```
filename = "Bibel.txt"
file = open(filename, mode="r", encoding="latin-1")

bibel_string = file.read()
bibel_list = file.readlines()

file.close()

# that works fine and generates the desired output
list(enumerate(bibel_string.splitlines()[:50], start=1))

# Attempt that does not run as desired
list(map(lambda x: enumerate(x.splitlines(), start=1), bibel_string))[:5]

# Output of attempt
[<enumerate at 0x1969a34b0>,
 <enumerate at 0x1969a35f0>,
 <enumerate at 0x1969a3640>,
 <enumerate at 0x1969a35a0>,
 <enumerate at 0x1969a36e0>]
```

Many thanks in advance for your efforts and your approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Map takes an iterable. The lambda you give to map is run once for each line in the iterable, but *only one at a time*. So inside the lambda, `x` is always just one line, not all of them. Therefore it doesn't make much sense to call `splitlines` on `x`, or to enumerate across `x`, which only has one part.

Instead, don't use `map` at all, just enumerate across the lines after you split them:

```py
list(enumerate(bibel_string.splitlines()))
```